# How to create a new dataframe from multiple lines of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python, and I think I may have gotten over my head with a project I started. I have an original dataset that comes in the form of an Excel spreadsheet that I'm importing as a dataframe. Each line of the dataframe is one status change from an individual transaction number, so each request makes up several lines of the data. I want to create a new dataframe that has 1 line for each transaction, with the columns being the time in the different statuses. Also, there may be multiple lines for the same status, which I would like to add together for a total. I'll Show an example input:

| df | Tran num | Status | Sub Status | Category | Time in Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Ready | NaN | Cats | 1.5 |
| 1 | 1 | Set | Set1 | Cats | 23 |
| 2 | 1 | Set | Set2 | Cats | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | Go | NaN | Cats | 14 |
| 4 | 2 | OnMark | NaN | Dogs | 3.5 |
| 5 | 2 | Getset | GS 1 | Dogs | 25 |
| 6 | 2 | OnMark | NaN | Dogs | 2.5 |
| 7 | 2 | Getset | GS 1 | Dogs | 22 |
| 8 | 2 | Getset | GS 2 | Dogs | 15 |
| 9 | 2 | Getset | GS 3 | Dogs | 12 |
| 10 | 2 | Go | NaN | Dogs | 18 |

Desired Output:

| df | Tran num | Category | T in Ready | T in Set | T in Go | T in Set1 | T in Set2 | T in OnMark | T in Getset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Cats | 1.5 | 43 | 14 | 23 | 20 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 2 | Dogs | NaN | NaN | 18 | NaN | NaN | 2.5 | 49 |

I'm not sure why, but the table looks fine in the editor, but not when I post.
[image: Screenshot]

A couple of notes: I left out the sub-statuses for Tran num 2 for space, but would like that included. Basically any new status that comes up, I'd like to create a new column. Also, the dataset is roughly 300k+ lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot(columns = 'Status', values = 'Time in Status')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.